# Slidetoggle called when dropdown option is focused

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/EhTJF/

Linked is an example of the issue I am running into.
When an element is hovered over, slidetoggle() is called to show a drop down list. When attempting to select an option in the ddl, slidetoggle() is called again and forces the ddl and the toggled element to collapse.

Any ideas of what I am doing incorrectly?

*Edit

The indented functionality is to allow a user to select an option from the drop down list and then afterwards allow the element to automatically toggle up.

Comment: What browser are you using? On Chrome, I can select something in the dropdown and then it all disappears

Comment: I'm getting the problem in both ie and ff14

Comment: Ah, I see, yeah IE9 and Firefox both won't let you select something. You might need to move away from using `slideToggle` and use `slideDown` on mouseenter and `slideUp` on mouseleave, then attach those event handlers to all your elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit complicated, but maybe something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer;
    $('.dropdown').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            var elm = $(this).find('.sub_navigation');
            if (!elm.is(':visible')) {
                elm.slideDown(100);
            }else{
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            var elm = $(this).find('.sub_navigation');
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                elm.slideUp(100);
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EhTJF/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The hover() method has 2 signatures. The first takes 2 parameters: one for a function that is called when the mouse enters the element and the second for a function that is called on exit. The second signature takes only a single function that is called for both enter and exit events. In your current example you are using the same function for both hover enter and hover exit; this is why your drop-down element is being hidden.

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

I have this example if you want the drop-down to remain open after the first hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/gwZbj/4/